# How do i show either the stop or reload button but not both at all times in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, profile

I put this in my userchrome.css in my profile directory.

```
#stop-button[disabled="true"] { display:none; }
#stop-button:not([disabled]) + #reload-button { display:none; }
```

but only the 1st line works not the 2nd one.

Comment: BTW, I think this belongs in superuser.

Comment: which browser are you testing in?
check this http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/

Comment: Still, it's not necessary to use :not, because when the button is enabled it stops being disabled so the style no longer applies. At least that's what the link I gave implies, I didn't actually test it.

Comment: the browser is firefox 3.6 on windows 7, and windows doesn't have a superuser, lol. it's my comp so I am admin if you are wondering though

Answer (score 1):

Get the "Stop-or-Reload Button" extension. Or if you want to manually edit userChrome.css, you can use this, courtesy of [Improve Firefox](http://improvefirefox.com/customize-firefox-gui/):

```
/* Remove Forward button when there's nothing to go forward to */
#forward-button[disabled="true"] { display: none }
/* Remove Stop button when there's no page loading */
#stop-button[disabled="true"] { display: none }
```

Comment: As I do not like executing any foreign code; I cannot use your first suggestion.
Also the code you gave does not do anything about the refresh button I originally asked about in the question.
Actually the code I gave does work(according to lifehacker) for firefox 3.5, but the 2nd line does not work in firefox 3.6.

Comment: It doesn't work? That's weird. Anyway, why can't you use the extension? I've been using it for a long time and it's not like it's a virus. IIRC, you can see the source if you open the .xpi file (it's like a .zip file).